# How do you statically asign an IP to a commissioned machine in MAAS?

Tags: maas

When you deploy a machine using MAAS, its network interface (e.g. eno1) is set to "auto" and MAAS will assign an IP during deployment.

In the MAAS UI, you can select an interface of a machine and configure it for auto, static, dhcp, or unconfigured.  If static, you can specify the IP address.

How do you do specify a static IP using the MAAS CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Identify the MAAS subnet you are using for the static IP.

   `maas maasadmin subnets read | jq '.[] | {id:.id,name:.name}' --compact-output`

   ---
2. Find the system IDs of the server you want to assign a static IP address.

   `maas maasadmin nodes read | jq '.[] | {hostname:.hostname,system_id: .system_id, status:.status}' --compact-output`

   ---
3. Identify the NIC of the machine that will receive the static assignment.

   `maas maasadmin interfaces read ${SYSTEM_ID} | jq '.[] | {iface_id:.id, name:.name, mac:.mac_address, vid:.vlan.vid, fabric:.vlan.fabric}' --compact-output`

   ---
4. If the NIC already has an "auto" link, identify this link and delete it.  (The NIC should be in an un-configured state before going to the next step.)

   `maas maasadmin interfaces read ${SYSTEM_ID} | jq '.[] | .links[] | {link_id:.id, mode:.mode, ipaddr:.ip_address}' --compact-output`

   `maas maasadmin interface unlink-subnet ${SYSTEM_ID} ${NIC_ID} id=${OLD_LINK_ID}`

   ---
5. Assign the static IP address:

   `maas maasadmin interface link-subnet ${SYSTEM_ID} ${NIC_ID} mode=STATIC subnet=${SUBNET_ID} ip_address=${STATIC_IP}`

   ---

A few extra notes:

- machines should be in the "ready" state (after commissioning, before deployment) before running the process.
- your MAAS DHCP settings may impact what IP addresses you can use for static. Specifically, you can't use a DHCP-owned address for static assignment.
- for hosts with more than one NIC, you can identify the correct NIC using its MAC address from step #3.
- take notice of the quoting <kbd>'</kbd> and piping <kbd>|</kbd> for the `jq` command.  The pipes inside the quotes are intentional.

Thank you to Canonical Tech Support for their help with this solution.